# Are PL embeddings homotopic to smooth ones?

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology

In particular, I'm interested in the case we have a PL embedding $f : S^1 \to M$ (for a smooth manifold $M$): can it be homotoped to a smooth embedding? I'm not very familiar with PL stuff, so I may be misusing terminology; by PL embedding I mean a continuous map which is a homeomorphism onto its image, along with a triangulation of S^1 and a triangulation of M relative to which $f$ is linear on each simplex.

Evidently, the difficulty in this problem is to perform the smoothing of $f$ in a way as to have the final function be an immersion.

It would also be interesting to learn the answer of this in the case of a general PL embedding between two smooth manifolds.

Comment: Any continuous map $N \to M$ between smooth manifolds is homotopic to an arbitrarily-close smooth map. Moreover, if $2 \dim N \leq \dim M$, then the approximation can be taken to be an immersion. If $N$ is compact and $2 \dim N +1 \leq \dim M$, then it can be an embedding.  This (plus ad-hoc arguments for $\dim M=1,2$) takes care of maps $S^1 \to M$.  Still, there are probably stronger general statements because you're starting with a PL embedding.

Comment: @squirrel: What's the argument for $\dim M = 2$ like?

Comment: I bet the answer to your question is yes. Just need to do it near the star of every simplex; a tubular neighborhood of its image is homeomorphic to R^n so you may as well do everything there. So inductively assume you have a PDiff embedding M -> N that's smooth on the k-skeleton. Prove by hand you can smooth embeddings Star((k+1)-simplex) -> R^n. Now glue this together what you had before to smooth it up on the next skeleton up. I think one can make this idea perfectly rigorous. In fact I think you can make it so that any PL embedding is (topologically) *isotopic* to a smooth embedding...

Comment: provided the PL manifold is smooth equipped with a smooth triangulation, of course.

Comment: @Kyle I wonder, how is your comment compatible with the answer by PVAL?

Comment: @M.Rumpy I don't see any contradiction, do you? PVAL is describing the half-dimensional case, i.e., $N \to M$ with $2 \dim N = \dim M$. Here generic approximation results still ensure that $N \to M$ is homotopic to an immersion, not an embedding. That is, you can a smoothly immersed 2-sphere in PVAL's 4-manifolds but not a smoothly embedded one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, this is false. In particular, it is false already for embeddings $S^2 \to M^4$. For example take the manifold given by attaching a $2$-handle to a right-handed trefoil in $S^3=\partial B^4$ with framing $0$ (the interior if you insist on no boundary). There is a $PL$-embedding of $S^2$ given by taking the core disk of the $2$-handle and gluing it to the cone on the knot in $B^4$. However, there are relatively strong conditions on when a homology class in $H_2(M^4, \Bbb Z)$   can be represented by a smoothly embedded sphere and in this case the homology class has no such representative (by say the adjunction inequality for Stein surfaces).

Comment: In essence, the same argument works for all non-slice knots, right?

Comment: @squirrel Maybe a similar proof works if you assume your knot isn't slice (most of the sliceness obstructions I know come by computing the genus of a closed surface in a 4-manifold anyway) , but understanding genus functions of even a simple $4$-manifold like the trace of a knot can be difficult. In the case of the unknot with framing $1$, this is the Thom conjecture.

Comment: The point here is that the right-handed trefoil has a Thurston-Bennequin number 1 embedding into $S^3$, and due to a theorem of (Gompf?)-Eliashberg, the manifold it admits a Stein structure and hence we can apply the adjunction inequality (of Kronheimer-Mrowka, and Ozsvath-Szabo) to see that no sphere represents the homology class (coming from a seifert surface union the core disk). This does also show the trefoil is not slice.

Comment: @squirrel Addition to the first comment: I do not know if a surface in the 4-ball glued to the core disk is a minimal genus representative for the generator of $H_2$ in the trace of a knot. This seems like it should be true though.

Comment: I certainly agree with all the elements of your argument, and its nice to see them spelled out.  But I was simply thinking that if we attach a 2-handle along any non-slice knot $K$ (examples of which can be found using easier obstructions like signature), the cone on $K$ in $B^4$ is a PL embedded disk. This disk can't be smoothed because $K$ is not slice.  And, if we want a closed surface, we can cap the disk off using the core of the 2-handle.

Comment: @Squirrel My issue is that the cone on the knot is certainly homotopic to a smooth embedding (even if not relative to the boundary). I don't see a reason (excluding some black-box from Heegard-Floer or Seiberg-Witten theory) that there cannot be an weird looking sphere representing the same homology class (which is not just the union of a core disk and a surface in the four ball). These things can certainly exist in more complicated 4-manifolds.